# Is an onject id returned when publishing via Facebook GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook

I am planning an app that will post to a users FB wall.  When posting via the GraphAPI is an object id returned for the new post?  We want to use the post id later to retrieve data about the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [`FB.ui()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui) example for stream.publish, `post_id` is returned with the response.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but really need to publish via a server-side call

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this example from their [FB.api docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api), it certainly seems possible.

```
var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { body: body }, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
    } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response);
    }
});
```